# Receiving a build error when upgrading to gradle 3.3 and android build tools 2.3.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I just updated my build files

Gradle from 2.14.1 to 3.3
Android Plugin from 2.2.3 to 2.3.0

I am receiving the following error. Seems like some thirdparty plugin issue. Can anyone shed light to it? I cant find anything in change logs related to this change.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':apis'.
>
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>
> The "android" command is no longer included in the SDK. Any references
> to it (e.g. by third-party plugins) should be removed.

The build file in which error is thrown looks something like this

```
apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
  compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(ANDROID_SDK_VERSION)
  buildToolsVersion ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

  // Legacy apache network stack
  useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(ANDROID_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
    targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(ANDROID_SDK_VERSION)
    consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
  }

  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
  }

  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
  }

  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
  }
}

...
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`android-apt` has been deprecated and, as per the [migration guide](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/wiki/Migration):

> As of the Android Gradle plugin version 2.2, all functionality that was previously provided by android-apt is now available in the Android plugin.

You can remove `android-apt` and follow the migration guide to get the equivalent functionality.

Similarly, as per the [sdk-manager-plugin page](https://github.com/JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin):

> This plugin is deprecated and is no longer being developed. Tools and dependencies are [automatically downloaded](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#download-with-gradle) using version 2.2.0 of the Android Gradle plugin or newer.

So it too can be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Want to summarize what it take for us to upgrade:

1. Upgrade to gradle 3.3 and android build tools 2.3.0

   ```
   -classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
   +classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
   ```

   and

   ```
   -distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
   +distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
   ```

   These should be done by Android Studio automatically when you upgrade.
2. Remove `android-apt` and `sdk-manager-plugin` as suggested by @ian

   ```
   -classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
   ```

   and

   ```
   -apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
   -apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
   ```

   These plugins are deprecated and no longer needed in newer version of gradle.
3. Change the build tool version number in the app/build.gradle file:

   ```
   -  buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
   +  buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
   ```
4. Search for all `apt` in the gradle file and replace with `annotationProcessor`. As an example, we are using AutoValue and Parceler and we'll have to do these:

   ```
   -  apt "com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-gson:$autoValueGsonVersion"
   +  annotationProcessor "com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-gson:$autoValueGsonVersion"
   ```

   and

   ```
   -  apt "org.parceler:parceler:$parcelerVersion"
   +  annotationProcessor "org.parceler:parceler:$parcelerVersion"
   ```
5. Finally, which is also important, clean and rebuild.